# "Limit along a radius vector"

Tags: complex-analysis

> Consider, where $z = x + iy$, the function
>   $$f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$$
>   $$f(z) =\left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   \frac{x^3y(y-ix)}{x^6+y^2}  & \mbox{if } z \neq 0 \\
>   0 & \mbox{if } z = 0
>  \end{array}
> \right.$$
>   Show that the increment ratio $\frac{f(z)−f(0)}{z}→0$ as $z→0$ along any radius vector but not as z→0 in any manner.

What does it mean to take a limit along a radius vector?

I don't think I've encountered this before.

Comment: A radius is the line segment going straight out from the center of a circle.

Comment: Is $z=x+i y$ ? ${}$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch yes, I'll edit that in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along a radius vector means along a "straight" direction that points to the origin, or formally the directional derivative
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(tz)-f(0)}{tz}$$
Where $z$ is any non zero complex number.

In any manner means the general definition of a limit i.e. 
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}.$$
where the limit is in the epsilon-delta sense, so we will focus on  *neighborhood*s instead of a specific path.